# Add a number to variable with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have got a problem with executing a function. What I am trying to achieve is when I click on the #loadmore the page variable should be increased by 1 number. And more items loaded from the server(at the moment when clicking it just loads the same).

```
$(document).on('click', '#blogs', function blogs() {
    $('#content, #category').empty();
    $('#category').prepend('<div class="categories_listing"><span data-type="blogs" data-category="5">Blog Category</span></div>');
    var count = "15";
    var page = "1"; 
        $.getJSON('https://domain.com/get_posts/?count=' + count + '&page=' + page, function (data, status) {
        if (data !== undefined && data.posts !== undefined) {
            $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
            var date = item.date;
            var dateSplit = date.split(" ");
            var dateSplit2 = dateSplit[0].split("-");
            var newDate = dateSplit2.reverse().join('-'); // 26-06-2013
            var str = item.title;
            $('#content').append('<div class="blogs_article" data-item="' + item.id + '"><div>' + str.substring(0, 1) + '</div>' + item.title + '<div>' + newDate + ' &mdash; ' + item.author.first_name +'</div></div>');
            if (data !== undefined) {
                $('#stats').text('Page ' + data.query.page + ' of ' + data.pages + ' | Total posts ' + data.count_total + '');
            }
            if (data.query.page < data.pages) {
                $("#loadmore").show();
            } else {
                $("#loadmore").hide();

            }
            page++;
            });
        }
    });
    $('#category').append('<div id="loadmore"><div id="stats"></div><div id="loadmore">load more</div></div>');
    $('#loadmore').click(blogs);
});
```

Please help me I have spend the whole night and couldn't make it working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the variable page must be declared outside the scope of the click callback other wise the variable will be in the local scope of the click function and will get reinitialized on each click event.

```
var page = 1;
$(document).on('click', '#blogs', function blogs() {
    $('#content, #category').empty();
    $('#category').prepend('<div class="categories_listing"><span data-type="blogs" data-category="5">Blog Category</span></div>');
    var count = "15";
    $.getJSON('https://domain.com/get_posts/?count=' + count + '&page=' + page, function (data, status) {
        if (data !== undefined && data.posts !== undefined) {
            $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
                var date = item.date;
                var dateSplit = date.split(" ");
                var dateSplit2 = dateSplit[0].split("-");
                var newDate = dateSplit2.reverse().join('-'); // 26-06-2013
                var str = item.title;
                $('#content').append('<div class="blogs_article" data-item="' + item.id + '"><div>' + str.substring(0, 1) + '</div>' + item.title + '<div>' + newDate + ' &mdash; ' + item.author.first_name + '</div></div>');
                if (data !== undefined) {
                    $('#stats').text('Page ' + data.query.page + ' of ' + data.pages + ' | Total posts ' + data.count_total + '');
                }
                if (data.query.page < data.pages) {
                    $("#loadmore").show();
                } else {
                    $("#loadmore").hide();

                }
            });
            page++;
        }
    });
    $('#category').append('<div id="loadmore"><div id="stats"></div><div id="loadmore">load more</div></div>');
    $('#loadmore').click(blogs);
});
```

Comment: hi Arun, it doesn't increase by one number, after a click it makes page = 16

Comment: @qqruza it was because `page++` was within the each loop, move it outside